# Maven NoSuchAlgorithmException when resolving dependencies

Tags: java, maven, ssl, javafx

my maven installation recently started throwing a NoSuchAlgorithmException when trying to download plugins and/or dependencies. (See stacktrace below). I'm using Intellij Idea community edition, but have tried running mvn clean install from the CLI as well. Same issue.

I've tried a lot of options on SO and other websites but no success. What I've tried thus far are a few variations of the following (I'm on a Windows 10 system):

- Upgrade to maven 3.5, was on 3.0
- Upgrade and downgrade my java installation to Zulu 19.30.11-jdk19.0.1 and Microsoft jdk17.0.2. This included changing my JAVA_HOME and path variables.
- Installed the https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ SSL certificate (repo.maven.apache.org.crt) downloaded via chrome to java folder lib/security/cacerts using the KeyTool.
- Add command line args: `-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true`
- Turn the computer off and on again :D

I have no idea why this is happening, but I hope someone can assist. If you need any further information, please let me know.

Stacktrace from CLI after running `mvn clean install -X` when trying to build [this JavaFX project from Github source](https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX):

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project module1: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.dlsc.jpackagefx:module1:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.openjfx:javafx-controls:jar:17.0.0.1: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.openjfx:javafx-controls:jar:17.0.0.1: Could not transfer artifact org.openjfx:javafx-controls:pom:17.0.0.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext): problem accessing trust store -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project module1: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.dlsc.jpackagefx:module1:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.openjfx:javafx-controls:jar:17.0.0.1
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:221)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:127)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved(MojoExecutor.java:246)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:200)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.dlsc.jpackagefx:module1:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.openjfx:javafx-controls:jar:17.0.0.1
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:177)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:195)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.collection.DependencyCollectionException: Failed to collect dependencies at org.openjfx:javafx-controls:jar:17.0.0.1
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:300)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:325)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:169)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.openjfx:javafx-controls:jar:17.0.0.1
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:283)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:199)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:544)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:528)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:418)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:372)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:360)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:263)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.openjfx:javafx-controls:pom:17.0.0.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:453)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:255)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:232)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:268)
        ... 33 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.openjfx:javafx-controls:pom:17.0.0.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:52)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:364)
        at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:76)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:590)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:258)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:529)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:430)
        ... 36 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1068)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:962)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:126)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter$GetTaskRunner.run(WagonTransporter.java:569)
        at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.execute(WagonTransporter.java:436)
        at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.get(WagonTransporter.java:413)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:456)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:359)
        ... 41 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
        at java.base/javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.throwException(SSLSocketFactory.java:267)
        at java.base/javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:289)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:363)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.execute(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:834)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:985)
        ... 50 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
        at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1868)
        at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:236)
        at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:164)
        at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:185)
        at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(SSLContext.java:110)
        at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(SSLSocketFactory.java:83)
        at java.base/javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory(HttpsURLConnection.java:336)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.createConnManager(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:348)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.<clinit>(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:274)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
        at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:86)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:105)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000(ConstructorInjector.java:32)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call(ConstructorInjector.java:89)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:87)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:267)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:65)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:63)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get(Guice4.java:162)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.transport.wagon.PlexusWagonProvider.lookup(PlexusWagonProvider.java:67)
        at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.lookupWagon(WagonTransporter.java:280)
        at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.<init>(WagonTransporter.java:124)
        at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporterFactory.newInstance(WagonTransporterFactory.java:136)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultTransporterProvider.newTransporter(DefaultTransporterProvider.java:119)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.<init>(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:124)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory.newInstance(BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory.java:189)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.newRepositoryConnector(DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.java:122)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:525)
        ... 37 more
Caused by: java.security.KeyManagementException: problem accessing trust store
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultManagersHolder.<clinit>(SSLContextImpl.java:942)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext.<init>(SSLContextImpl.java:1111)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
        at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.newInstanceOf(Provider.java:1879)
        at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.newInstanceUtil(Provider.java:1886)
        at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1861)
        ... 89 more
```

Comment: Why have you not upgraded to most recent Maven version 3.8.7 (https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) Do not turn off security of the SSL (`-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching a bit further when updating to maven 3.8.7, I inspected my Path variables and noted the following System Variable:

```
MAVEN_OPTS

-Xmx512m -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.8.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=xxxxxxxx
```

This pointed to a specific certificate - leading all my maven versions to use an outdated or possibly deleted certificate. I deleted this variable and the maven build worked.

I checked all the other java and maven variables and made sure they make sense.

Comment: The certs are by default correct and its not needed to import them into the cacerts file...

Comment: I realized that. Thanks for your help. My guess is that the OPTS variable was set a few years ago when I installed either maven or a jdk or an IDE. I wasn't even aware it was there.